# HTTP 500 – Wordpress WP-API without any message?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, wp-api

I'm using [themosis](http://framework.themosis.com/) – a framework for wordpress that works pretty well. Also I use [WP-API](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API) - that doesn't work so great.

All versions are the latest stables and the Server is using PHP 5.5

On calling that API route:

```
posts?filter[order]=ASC&filter[orderby]=name&filter[posts_per_page]=-1&type=products
```

I'm getting an Internal Server error / HTTP 500

> ## Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, webmaster@example.ch and
>   inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might
>   have done that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

So my hoster checked the logs and the only lines caused by this error were:

```
[Tue Jul 07 17:43:13 2015] [error] Premature end of script headers: php55-fcgi-starter.fcgi, referer: {myurl/mypath}
```

I checked all log, forced everything to display errors & logs, but no PHP errors - not even notices... (set `display_errors` to `On` and `error_reporting` to `2039` - with htaccess and php-side (wordpress index.php)

---

I just figured out that when I set the `post_per_page` filter is set to e.g. 90 it works, but only till a specific post.

All posts are "normal" - making a `WP_Query` also delivers all results without any issues.

---

I also increased the php memory_limit to more than enough and tested it locally (Mac OS / MAMP) what works great.

I really can't find any reason why this is happening. My server hoster support (which is really good actually) says also that all systems run fine

Comment: Are you running out of memory on the query, or perhaps running past your script execution limit?

Comment: @drmarvelous The whole request just takes 800ms, the php max execution time is set to 30s – php memory limit is set to temp. 1G what also didnt solve the error

Comment: Just found a bug in the WP-API plugin: https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/issues/1404